# What filter should I use to send ArrayList by using apache-MINA

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio, apache-mina

I have server and client applications with apache-mina framework. I need to send a large arraylist (contains 10000 custom objects) from server to client. I first thought to use GSON strings to pass the arraylist, but I think, creating that kind of huge strings and sending it is not a proper way.

In my client app, I wrote a method to connect :

```
public void connect() throws InterruptedException 
{

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

            connector = new NioSocketConnector();
            connector.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(1024);
            TextLineCodecFactory t = new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            t.setEncoderMaxLineLength(100000);
            t.setDecoderMaxLineLength(100000);
            connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
            connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(t));

            connector.setHandler(handler);
            ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", PORT));
            future.awaitUninterruptibly();

            if (!future.isConnected()) 
            {
                return;
            }

            IoSession session = future.getSession();
            session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
            session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

            connector.dispose();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

What filter should I use to send objects or containers without converting them into strings ? Is it about BufferedWriteFilter or WriteRequestFilter ? If so how can I use them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

By using ObjectSerializationCodecFactory on both client and server side, I can pass custom objects and collections.

```
  ObjectSerializationCodecFactory oscf = new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory();
  oscf.setDecoderMaxObjectSize(1048576);
  connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(oscf)
```